# The set of continuous functions vanishing at $c$ is not the principal ideal generated by $x-c$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R = \mathcal C([0,1], \mathbb R)$ and $M_c = \{f \in R \mid  f(c) = 0\}$.
I would like to show that:

a. $M_c \neq M_b$ if $b \neq c$ ;

b. $M_c$ is not the principal ideal generated by $x-c$;

c. $M_c$ is not finitely generated.

For a. I think its clear that if $f(x)=x-c$ then $ f \in M_c $ and $f \in M_b$ iff $b=c$.

b. is trickier. I'm thinking about something like $f=|x-c|$ because then if $f=g(x-c)$ then $g=|x-c|/(x-c)$ and then  $g \notin R$.

This doesn't feel good enough. How can I make this precise or am I even on the right track?

EDIT; Suppose $c \neq 1$. Let  $f(x)=(x-c)^{1/2}\chi_{x > c}$. Clearly $f \in M_c$. Suppose $(x-c)$ divides $f$ Then $f= g(x-c)$ for some $g \in \mathcal{R}$. I want to go for $g \notin \mathcal{R}$ but I'm pretty sure I cannot say $g=\frac{f}{x-c}$ because $x-c$ is not a unit...so I'm stuck here.

EDIT2; Ok I think I have it.  Suppose $x>c$. If we calculate:

$$|g(x)-g(c)|=|\frac{f(x)}{x-c}-g(c)|\geq|x-c|^{-1/2}-|g(c)| \geq 1 - |g(c)|$$  So $g$ has no right limit as $x \rightarrow c$ and therefore $g \notin R$

Comment: For b) your counterexample works, you just need to be a bit more specific about why. That is, you want to prove formally that your $f$ is not divisible by $x - c$. And you also need a different example for $c = 0, 1$. For c) try to construct more functions in $M_c$, not in the ideal generated by your previous ones, to get a better sense of how big it is.

Comment: Is "cts" short for "continuous"?

Comment: yes. I get tired of spelling it wrong.

Comment: I made some edits. I think this is better, yeah?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose that $M_c$ is finitely generated by $\{f_1, \dots, f_n\}$.

$$f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{\vert f_i(x) \vert}$$ is an element of $M_c$. Therefore, $f= \sum_{i=1}^n g_if_i$ with $g_1, \dots, g_n \in R$ and

$$\vert f(x) \vert \le M \sum_{i=1}^n \vert f_i(x) \vert$$ where $M = \sup\limits_{1 \le i \le n} \Vert g_i \Vert_\infty$. By continuity, it exists an open $U$ containing $c$ such that for all $x \in U$ and $1 \le i \le n$:
$$\sqrt{\vert f_i(x) \vert} \le \frac{1}{2M}.$$

Then
$$\vert f(x) \vert \le M \sum_{i=1}^n \vert f_i(x) \vert =M \sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{\vert f_i(x) \vert}\sqrt{\vert f_i(x) \vert} \le \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{\vert f_i(x) \vert} = \frac{1}{2} \vert f(x) \vert.$$

Consequently $f, f_1, \dots, f_n$ vanish on $U$. A contradiction as $x \mapsto \vert x - c \vert$ belongs to $M_c$ and only vanishes at $c$.

Comment: What is stopping $max\{|x-c|,1\}$ from being one of your $f_i's?$.  This feels like it should be at odds with your conclusion. Though I've been looking for some time and I can't see what fails..

Comment: Why is the n necessary in your bound for $\sqrt{|f_i(x)|}$?

Comment: You're right that the hypothesis is not necessary in my proof... Therefore I removed it.