# Question about logic in continuity proof.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification

I originaly asked [The set of continuous functions vanishing at $c$ is not the principal ideal generated by $x-c$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3814813/the-set-of-continuous-functions-vanishing-at-c-is-not-the-principal-ideal-gene) , but I think this is differnt enough to warrant a different question.

To summarize;

Let $R = \mathcal C([0,1], \mathbb R)$ and $M_c = \{f \in R \mid  f(c) = 0\}$.

I would like to show $M_c$ is not generated by x-c. Below is my attempt.

Suppose $c \neq 1$. Let  $f(x)=(x-c)^{1/2}\chi_{x > c}$. Clearly $f \in M_c$. Suppose $(x-c)$ divides $f$. Then $f= g(x-c)$ for some $g \in \mathcal{R}$.  I'm pretty sure I cannot say $g=\frac{f}{x-c}$ because $x-c$ is not a unit (please verify).

Suppose $x>c$ and $x-c < \delta$
$$|g(x)-g(c)|=|\frac{f(x)}{x-c}-g(c)|\geq|x-c|^{-1/2}-|g(c)| \geq 1 - |g(c)|$$  So $g$ has no right limit as $x \rightarrow c$ and therefore $g \notin R$

This feels very strange.  My proof relys on g(c) being a fixed value, but my proof also shows that $g(c)$ does not even exist. Of course $g(c)<\infty$ is consistent with $g\in \mathcal{R}$, but this is the very thing I'm contradicting. I can't tell if I'm just overthinking this or if this is a true logical error.

Comment: What is $\delta$?

Comment: It dosn't matter what delta is since $|g(x)-g(c)|$ will never be less than $1-|g(c)|$? That is, for $\epsilon< 1-|g(c)|$ there will never be a delta s.t. $|g(x)-g(c)|<\epsilon$